# iPhone Artifact when Selecting Image from Phone in Webview

Tags: jquery, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, amazon-web-services, webview

This issue just started happening recently and not sure if it's related to migration from linode to AWS, tbh I don't see how it could be.

Basically when user opens our app it's a webview to shouttag.com (80 is redirected to 443), and everything works as expected, except when a user uploads an image. When the iPhone attempts to load the native menu, we are seeing the following artifact:

[image]

It appears as though the native menu which allows the user to 'Use Existing' or 'Take New' is not fully rendering for some reason.

We are currently using the following frontend stack:

- jquery: 2.1.4
- bootstrap: 3.3.4
- bootswatch (spacelab): 3.3.4
- Test phone ios: v9.1

Nothing about the frontend stack has changed, only the aforementioned move from linode to AWS.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This artifact was caused by ios upgrade from 8.x to 9.x, I had to publish an entirely new binary which was ios9 compatible to resolve the problem. However I was able to implement the new SFSafariViewController which fixed some other issues, like FB and Twitter integration.